# python pandas: nested dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transfer a nested dic to a dataframe. (The dataframe should not be nested, only the highest layer from the dic should be converted to a dataframe).

```
dic =  {'Key1': 
                  {'Key1_1': [],
                   'Key1_2': 
                            {'Key1_2_1':
                                    {'Key1_2_1_1': 'value1_2_1_1'},
                              'Key1_2_2': ['listelement1value1_2_2']}},
        'Key2': 'value2', 
        'Key3': 'value3', 
        'Key4': 'value4'}
```

with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dic, index=[0])
```

i get:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    |   Key1 | Key2   | Key3   | Key4   |
|----+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|  0 |    nan | value2 | value3 | value4 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

with

```
series = pd.Series(dic)
df = series.to_frame().T

+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|    | Key1                                                                                                           | Key2   | Key3   | Key4   |
|----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------|
|  0 | {'Key1_1': [], 'Key1_2': {'Key1_2_1': {'Key1_2_1_1': 'value1_2_1_1'}, 'Key1_2_2': ['listelement1value1_2_2']}} | value2 | value3 | value4 |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

and the second result is that what i want.
Is there a better way to get the second result without using a series first ?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your approach, looks fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dic])
print (df)
                                                Key1    Key2    Key3    Key4
0  {'Key1_1': [], 'Key1_2': {'Key1_2_1': {'Key1_2...  value2  value3  value4
```